# Is it possible to enable compression with SQL Server 2005 Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, configuration, compression, replication

I am sending data across a link with very little bandwidth and I will probably be sending large data files.

I have Merge Replication and Snapshot replication configured at present.

Is it possible to enable compression in SQL Server 2005 replication and if so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google turned up this article on the Microsoft SQL Server Development Customer Advisory Team [sic!] Blog:

[SQL Server 2005 Transactional Replication: Benefit of using SubscriptionStreams for low bandwidth, high latency environments](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlcat/archive/2007/05/07/sql-server-2005-transactional-replication-benefit-of-using-subscriptionstreams-for-low-bandwidth-high-latency-environments.aspx)

Not exactly what you were asking for, but maybe of value still.

Comment: Thanks for that Tomalak, very interesting indeed. 

as you said, not exactly what I was looking for, but certainly something to consider. 
Thanks.